# How come my simple JQuery code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://github.com/tobia/CrossSlide/raw/master/jquery.cross-slide.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(function(){
                    $(".imagedivholder").each(function(e){
                        $(this).crossSlide({ speed:45, fade:1
                                },[
                                {src: $(this).attr("rel"), dir:'up' },
                                {src: $(this).attr("rel"), dir:'down' },
                                ]
                            });

                        });


            });

</script>
```

And these are my divs...

```
<div class="awallpost"> 
            <div class="imagedivholder" rel="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3458/3889274600_f381d28003.jpg" > 
                <!--<a href="document/show?id=4cde4c258aad69014a0000e1"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/4e0bndzxsaf3qul2" width="230" height="230"></a>--> 
                 <div class="trans_caption"> 
                     <div style="padding:6px"> 
                    The Docks and The City: ...
                    </div> 
                 </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

        <div class="awallpost"> 
            <div class="imagedivholder" rel="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3454/3814350374_d37f82124b.jpg" > 
                <!--<a href="document/show?id=4cde4e1c8aad69014a00011e"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/vbparxeymqgndc8l" width="230" height="230"></a>--> 
                 <div class="trans_caption"> 
                     <div style="padding:6px"> 
                    Earth&#39;s paradise?
                    </div> 
                 </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.imagedivholder {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px;
    width:230px;
    height:230px;

}
```

I followed all the instructions here:
http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/

Comment: Learn how to use a `Web inspector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got one extra `}` after the last `]`.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, you've got a simple syntax error.

```
$(function(){
    $(".imagedivholder").each(function(e){
        $(this).crossSlide({
            speed:45, fade:1
        },[
            { src: $(this).attr("rel"), dir:'up' },
            { src: $(this).attr("rel"), dir:'down' },
        ]);
    });
});
```

Try learning to use [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com). It'll help you spot simple errors like these. If you still have problems, let us know.